# Implementing a "leaky bucket"-like algorithm for message queues

Tags: ruby, redis, rabbitmq, throttling, rate-limiting

I have a ruby based application that has many different message queues (+200 different queues) that all needs to be throttled/rate limited individually. I have tried to illustrate the problem using this candy vending machine analogy

[image: Leaky Candy Vending Machine]

Now how would I go about implementing a system/algorithm like this? I have been thinking about putting the messages/"candy" into different redis lists/sets or RabbitMQ queues but getting them popped out from each queue at individual rates seems to be a hard task. Are there some technologies out there that would be better suited for the job than redis?

Comment: You can implement it in lua in redis and calling the script from ruby. Complex reads and writes should be done in lua, less network roundtrips, good language, atomic behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) (which also uses Redis for persistence). You could use a different queue for each type of 'candy' and start up a worker for each queue with different values for the `--interval` option.

```
$ bin/resque work --queues=blue  --interval=10
$ bin/resque work --queues=green --interval=2
$ bin/resque work --queues=red   --interval=5
```